# What's the difference between installing files with pip and copy-pasting

Tags: python, pip, installation

When you're installing modules to python usually you use pip install. Does pip install do anything other than put the modules in the right place? Why can't you just copy and paste the modules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using pip not only copies the modules in the right place, it also properly installs dependencies. In addition, the right place varies from one system to another, one version of python to another, and pip handles that as well.

Finally, copying and pasting files takes either manual intervention, or a lot more lines of script than a simple pip install.

Comment: Ok thanks. So assuming you have python fully setup and installed with all the modules you need to run a program, you could copy and paste it and everything would be in the right place (instead of installing it again)? Maybe I need to change the PATH variable but that's it?

Comment: very true. just wanted to say very true, but was forced to say more. ;-)

Comment: @user3364161 if you had everything already installed, you wouldn't need to copy anything.

Comment: I mean, if you are in that position, and the systems are otherwise the same, then I guess you could. However, in that case, it's still one line to pip install and either using the UI or multiple cp lines to install via copy and paste. If the system is different, then I think there could be issues with permissions or compilation

Answer (score 1):

Using pip to install modules is first easier(just need to use pip install).
And pip also automatically install all the dependencies needed for the module to run.

It's a lot more work to copy and paste especially downloading from pypi since most modules are stored in a .wheel file and has many versions. Pip will install the correct one for your version of python and runs setup.py automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Python packages typically have a `setup.py` that could do anything from copying a module to building c extensions. Its also common to byte-compile .py files assuming that later users wouldn't have rights to do so after install. You can build distributions with `setup.py`, so you could for instance, build a binary distribution for a specific operating system and distribute that. But these days, a popular way to install things is to build a python wheel and let pip do the work for you.

Comment: Where is actually pip putting the files. I have a directory with a `setup.py` in it. This get installed with `python2.7 -m pip install -e .` But where are the packages copied to? The site packages folder is empty.